# read next line after the matched string and assign the value to variable

Tags: batch-file

As part of a task that I am working on, I need to extract "ID" of a particular resource (from a .txt file) and assign it to a variable.

```
Resource:          Logging
ID:                7BE-3F19-F441-AA26
NodeID:                   
Description:       Logging
Version:           0.5.11
Revision:          1
```

I was able to find "Resource" in the .txt file

```
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
@echo off

SET RESOURCE_NAME="Logging"
SET LOGFILE="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\batlog.txt"

FOR /F "tokens=* %%a IN ('findstr /c:"%RESOURCE_NAME%" %LOGFILE%') DO echo %%a
```

Still I can not figure out how to match next line, extract the value of "ID" and assign it to a variable. Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code filtering on `Logging` you can't ***see*** any other lines.

- Read all lines, remember the last one.
- When conditions are met, store ID and abort loop.
- you'll need to [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html).

---

```
:: Q:\Test\2019\04\22\SO_55800720.cmd
@echo off & SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET "LOGFILE=%USERPROFILE%\DeskTop\Batlog.txt"

FOR /F "usebackqtokens=1* delims=: " %%a IN ("%LOGFILE%") DO (
  If /i "!Last!"=="Resource:Logging" if /i "%%a"=="ID" (Set "ID=%%b"&Goto :Found)
  Set "Last=%%a:%%b"
)
Echo Couldn't find ID:
pause
Goto :Eof

:Found
echo Found ID: %ID%
```